# Get second flat array's values not found in first flat array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-difference

I have to arrays and I have to find difference values from it.
Here is my Laravel Controller code

```
 $product_list = Operation::where('kvit_id', $kvit->id)->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
 $hamkor_products = ListProduct::where('user_id', $newkvit->user_id)->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
 $operProductList =  array_diff($product_list, $hamkor_products);
 dd($product_list, $hamkor_products, $operProductList);
```

Here is result which I'm getting

[image]

What kind of mistake I made? `$operProductList` is returns `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must just change the order of parameters in `array_diff()`, it must be like :

```
$product_list = Operation::where('kvit_id', $kvit->id)->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
 $hamkor_products = ListProduct::where('user_id', $newkvit->user_id)->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
 $operProductList =  array_diff($hamkor_products, $product_list);
 dd($product_list, $hamkor_products, $operProductList);
```